# Output to another Window

Tags: vb.net, io, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to direct a form in VB.NET to open and maximize in the second monitor. That is if there are two monitors displayed, to have the form load in the second window maximized by default?

Say a program was made with two forms and a computer has two monitors attached.

I want FormA to show in MonitorA by default and FormB to show in MonitorB maximized by default.

EDIT: Further edited for clarity.

Comment: When you say _window_, do you mean a window as in one that you can minimize and maximize, or are you in fact referring to a _monitor screen_? I find the question a bit unclear.

Comment: I'm in fact referring to another monitor screen.

Comment: Then I don't quite understand what you mean by *"have the form load in the second window"*. What is a form in this context? Is this a winforms, WPF or ASP.NET project?

Comment: WinForms project. I mentioned specifically VB.NET as the language.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications; the question makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to get information about available screens. You can get that from [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx). Next is to determine how many screens there are (note that there may be more than two). Then you need to decide how to identify the "second" screen (for instance, the first one that where the [`Primary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primary.aspx) property is `false`.

When that is done, I guess that the simplest way is to move the form to a location that is within the [`Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx) of the desired screen, and then maximize it.

Here is a sample method that opens a form maximized on a specified screen:

```
public static void ShowMaximizedOnScreen(Screen screen, Form form)
{
    form.Location = screen.Bounds.Location;
    form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: @PaulWilliams I just noticed that your question was tagged with vb.net, but I hope the code sample is usable anyway.