# Move Form if second monitor screen exists

Tags: vb.net, multiple-monitors

Looking for a way to load a from if a second screen exists.

I have tried this code with a load event:

```
Dim numofMon As Integer = Screen.AllScreens.Length
If numofMon > 1 Then
            Me.Bounds = Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds
        End If
```

Side note: If someone could point me to how to detect when the cursor is no longer on the form, I would appreciate it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413250/output-to-another-window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up working for me.

```
Dim obj as New Form2
obj.Location = Screen.AllScreens(UBound(Screen.Allscreens)).Bounds.Location
obj.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to place the form on the second screen, set the [WindowStartUpLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation(v=vs.110).aspx) to Manual before setting the Bounds. This causes the form to be positioned according to its Left and Top property values. These will then be set by changing the Bounds property as you already did.

To detect if the cursor is above the form that's currently focused, use the [MouseEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [MouseLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

Comment: I had the Forms `StartPosition` already set to Manual when I tried this. It just does not what to move to the second screen. Also tried `MouseLeave` but it also did not budge.

Comment: I have no reliable way to try and reproduce this, I only have 1 monitor. Maybe someone else can give this a go? By the way, it's probably better to use the [Screen.WorkingArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.110).aspx) property, Screen.Bounds as I understand it doesn't exclude the windows taskbar while WorkingArea does. Also, can you try the [SetBounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad5ah3k5(v=vs.110).aspx) sub instead of Me.Bounds?