# VB program refuse to follow my config file settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Just finished making cosmetic modifications on an existing program when I come across an issue.

This program have a configuration file to tell the program specifically what database to access, what user and password to use and what position should it open on screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="LocalDB" value="server=[REDACTED];database=[REDACTED];uid=[REDACTED];pwd=[REDACTED]" />
<add key="Refresh(sec)" value="5" />
<add key="Xpos" value="1024" /> -- THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA
<add key="LoopRec" value="24" />
<add key="Zone" value="ALL" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Xpos is the key which tells the program on which part of the screen should it open on. Reason being that the program must be opened at the extended screen (TV). However after making the cosmetic changes on the program and when I try to test it on site, the program opens on the main screen. Even after trying to change the value of Xpos, the program won't move anywhere else. What's weird is that only Xpos config is having problems. Everything else is working as intended.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        LocalDAL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("LocalDB")
        LocalDAL.Provider = EnumProviders.SQLClient
        Me.gintRefresh = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Refresh(sec)")
        Me.gintLoopRec = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("LoopRec")
        Me.gzone = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Zone")
        If Me.gzone <> "ALL" Then
            Me.lblPID.Text = Me.lblPID.Text & " [Zone: " & Me.gzone & "]"
        End If
        Me.tmrGrid.Interval = Me.gintRefresh * 1000
        Me.tmrGrid.Enabled = True
        Me.subDefineGrid()

        Me.SetDesktopLocation(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Xpos"), 0)
        Me.Location = New Point(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Xpos"), 0)
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

        strSQL = "SELECT DataStr FROM tblParam WHERE DataName='AlarmFile'"
        Me.gstrWavFile = Me.LocalDAL.ExecScalar(strSQL, CommandType.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.subErrLog("frmMain_Load", ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You're maximizing the window!  That seems to make the xpos irrelevant anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: I also noticed it at the last minute as well. I changed to Normal and it works. Can't I tell it to maximize on the 2nd screen though?

Answer (score 0):

Why not determine the screens available and then change the window location to the screen you desire instead of assuming the `Xpos` of the second screen? See this:
[Output to another Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413250/output-to-another-window)

Comment: Actually the method above was created by another member and it was at the perfect position. It was only when I made my changes then the Xpos don't wanna work and I don't know why as my changes is completely unrelated to the config file.

Comment: Have you tried the old version of the program again to see if it still works? Perhaps someone changed the screen configuration?

Comment: old version still works. It's running every day. Also can confirm no one touched the code before me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the namespace in your cosmetic changes? Then you also have to adjust the namespace in the tag of your app.config, and everything works again as expected.